# R: having a trouble generating xpath when webscraping on R

Tags: r, xpath

I am working to web scrape the following website:

```
   http://www.crowdrise.com/waterforpeople-SE
```

if you take a look at this website, on the righthand side, right above the black button that says `Fundraise for this campaign`, there is a statement saying: `52% Raised of $20,000 Goal`.
I am trying to extract this very statement that I just mentioned.

for xpath expression I tried:

```
  .//*[@id="thebody"]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/p/span
```

but it didn't work...

what is the correct xpath expression?

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
> library(XML)
> doc <- htmlTreeParse('http://www.crowdrise.com/waterforpeople-SE', useInternalNodes = TRUE)
> xpathApply(doc, '//div[@class="grid1-4"]//p[@class="progressText"]')
[[1]]
<p class="progressText">
  <span>52% Raised of $20,000 Goal</span>
</p> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

Or directly go for the text value:

```
> xpathApply(doc, '//div[@class="grid1-4"]//p[@class="progressText"]', xmlValue)
[[1]]
[1] "52% Raised of $20,000 Goal"
```

Comment: thank you! how did you figure this out? true, I am not good at xpath to begin with but i tried for hours and hours and just couldn't figure it out :)

Comment: Well, just look for unique HTML elements in the document :) If you have difficulties to define that with `xpath`, you may also use [CSS selectors in R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/selectr/index.html) or install an extension in your browser that can identify the `xpath` expression for you. E.g. there are bunch of similar applications for Chrome, but I am pretty sure there are also for FF.